# How get the value of method with parameters in another class java?

Tags: java

How get the value of ***method with parameters*** in another class java ?
For this example:

```
public double getTotalUtilizationOfCpu(double time) {
    double totalUtilization = 0;
    for (ResCloudlet rcl : getCloudletExecList()) {
        totalUtilization += rcl.getCloudlet().getUtilizationOfCpu(time);
    }
    return totalUtilization;
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the another class and call the function.

First Java class
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Class A {
  public double getFunction(double val) {
     ...  
     return someVal;
  }
}
```

Second Java class
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
import <fromwhereever>.A
Class B {
  public void useAnother() {
    A aClass = new A();
    double result = aClass.getFunction(123.45);
  }
 }
```

Comment: If the method has several parameters for example: getFunction(double val , int a, double time)

Comment: Why is it that you think that having more parameters all of a sudden means you have to do it in a whole different way?